# image onload not working , error Uncaught TypeError: Type error

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas

I want to draw the images using `image = new Image();`

I define new varible with three different images.

when I run the code I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Type error "

How to fix correctly the code to draw all the images which include in the varible images.

[Demo jsFFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/8p9ad/1/)

Many thanks.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 1000;
    canvas.height = 500;
var BACKGROUND = {
  p1:  { url : "http://flora4me.com/im/b/1149.jpg",x:   5, y:   5, w: 1280, h: 480 , dx:0 ,dy:0   ,dw:500 ,dh:500 },
  p2:  { url : "http://flora4me.com/im/b/1119.jpg",x:   5, y: 495, w: 1280, h: 480 , dx:100 ,dy:100 ,dw:500 ,dh:500},
  p3:  { url : "http://vladfilippov.com/blog/2012-12-07/intro.jpg",x:   5, y: 985, w: 1280, h: 480 , dx:200 ,dy:200 ,dw:500 ,dh:500 }
  };
var  image;
for (var n in BACKGROUND)
{
    image = new Image();
    image.src = BACKGROUND[n].url;
    image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, BACKGROUND[n].x,BACKGROUND[n].y, BACKGROUND[n].w, BACKGROUND[n].h, BACKGROUND[n].dx, BACKGROUND[n].dy, BACKGROUND[n].dw, BACKGROUND[n].dh );   
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you're drawing `p3` three times rather than iterate over the `BACKGROUND`. Though this won't explain the "Type error". Probably you're using a library, which adds properties to the Object prototype. To fix these, switch `BACKGROUND` to an Array and create your loop like this:

```
for (var n = 0; n < BACKGROUND.length; n++) {
    image = new Image();
    (function (x) {image.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(image, BACKGROUND[x].x,BACKGROUND[x].y, BACKGROUND[x].w, BACKGROUND[x].h, BACKGROUND[x].dx, BACKGROUND[x].dy, BACKGROUND[x].dw, BACKGROUND[x].dh);   
        }
    }(n));
    image.src = BACKGROUND[n].url;
}
```

You can also preserve the `BACKGROUND` object, but in that case you need to check the property being expected at the first line in the `for..in`:

```
if (!BACKGROUND.hasOwnProperty(n)) continue;
```

Comment: the code Looks good but it still not working see yourself  [Demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8p9ad/4/)

Comment: Hmm... your fiddle throws an `IndexSizeError`, there's something wrong with the size of the canvas or source rectangle...Please check [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage%28%29) at MDN.